# c# How do you get the base.Name from PropertyInfo

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

I am stepping though some code and looking at a PropertyInfo object and want to know how to get its base.Name

[alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/propertyinfo.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/propertyinfo.png)

I can see this in the debugger but I am not sure how to do this as there is no "base" property on a PropertyInfo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access this property via property.Name.

The fact that the debugger shows base.Name is a bit of a misnomer.  In reality the C# EE is evaluating property.Name under the hood.  It does not actually evaluate "base.Name".

This is true regardless of whether or not the property / method is virtual.  The reason being that the CLR deubgger provides no means by which the EE can invoke a virtual method in a non-virtual method.  There are ways to call a method via relfection to achieve this effect but neither C# or VB.Net go this route in their respective EE's.

Answer (score 6):

Just use `.Name`; `PropertyInfo` doesn't define this - it inherits it from `MemberInfo`

Answer (score 2):

Just:

```
property.Name
```